# Validate Manually Created Typescript Definition Files

Tags: typescript, typescript-definitions

**Background**

I have created a component library using react (plain js).  I am in the process of creating Typescript definitions for the components so that consumers of the component library can use the components in a type-safe manner in their Typescript applications.

**Question**

What is the recommended way, if there is one, to check that the definitions manually created are correct?  I am trying to catch issues before consumers have to highlighting any problems.

**Investigation so far...**

I have looked at https://github.com/asgerf/tscheck but it doesn't always work.

I also looked at DefinitelyTyped contribution guide:  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#create-a-new-package.  This says to create a typescript file with sample code for type-checking only...is this just a matter of compiling the `*.test.ts` file with the typescript compiler?

Comment: TypeScript code (like any other code) will be "correct" once there are no compile errors - so is your question about how to write correct `.d.ts` files?

Comment: I recently came across [this paper](https://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/papers/tstest/paper.pdf) which discusses this topic. Maybe it's useful to you.

Comment: In a way... more along the lines of " I have written a `.d.ts` file I believe to be correct. Is there a way to confirm that what I think is correct is in fact correct...From your answer it appears that I need to write some typescript that uses the definitions